# Cannot find module 'vscode' - Missing VSCode engine declaration in package.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a VSCode extension ([package.json](https://github.com/Timen-Stepisnik-Perdih/Parsaur_Language_Server/blob/main/parsaur_server/package.json)) and I get the "**Error: Cannot find module 'vscode'**" whenever I run it.

I've already tried running

```
npm install
```

and it did not help.
When I run

```
node ./node_modules/vscode/bin/install
```

I get "**Error installing vscode.d.ts: Missing VSCode engine declaration in package.json.**".

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "vscode" dev dependency. No idea what that is for.

Comment: I must admit I don't either. Unfortunately it did not solve the issue, however.

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` is out of date, and is still using a *deprecated definition*. This has been changed, if I remember correctly, a couple of years ago.

You should update your dependency to something like

```json
 "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.73.0"
    ...
  }
```

And don't forget to update the `engines` entry as well, to reflect the *minimun* VS Code version your extension will support.

```json
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.73.0"
    },
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: Create a new empty extension using `yo code` generator, and look how `package.json` is populate. If, you still have issues with `npm install` on this new empty extension, there must be some problem with your Node.js installation or internet access. If no error occurs, update the entries on your `package.json` file to be equals to the suggested new extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is yet, and I'll be back if I figure it out, but I'm assuming this is expecting to be run in VS Code, and I'm not doing that. I'm trying to create an LSP client outside of VS Code, and I think thats the rub.